# How would you test this calculator?

Tags: interview

A short while ago I applied for a QA internship. The first round of interviews involved a video conference call with some of the Software Testers from the company. At some point during the interview they asked me to demonstrate how I would test the Calculator application installed on Windows 7 machines.

I admit I was a bit lost for what to do. To my best ability, I tested out simple arithmetic equations, unit conversion, and keyboard vs mouse input. I did not get the job.

This led me to ask, as a Software Tester, what sort of things would you look for in a candidate if you gave them this kind of test?

Comment: I found a lot of answers by Googling "how to test a calculator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of us would be looking for various buzz words. Test plan, edge cases, partitioning, black box, requirements, specification. The candidate who looks like they know how to structure a test plan and actually knows something about software testing theory would score points.

Answer (score 0):

1).test the display.
2).0-9 keys
3).-+*/
4).=
5).Clear button
Those are high priority

Then low priority
all the other keys.